# Stemming the tide of emails of other people's questions

Tags: support, email-notification

Since I've joined I've noticed that I'm receiving much more mail about others' questions each day.

How can I stop that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364979?tab=preferences#tab-top) tab in your account page and uncheck the `"I'd like email notifications of activity on questions I've asked"` check box.